# Word boundaries in mixed-alphabet words

Tags: unicode, words

By default (e.g., in fundamental mode), emacs seems to treat the sequence of characters `abcαβγ` in a buffer as two separate words. In particular, a command like `M-f` done at the beginning will only move past the `abc`.

I have trouble understanding what is going on and how to change this behaviour. I thought that the definition of a word is a sequence of characters with syntax class `w`, but here all six characters have syntax class `w` yet it is treated as two different words.

I tried to use `superword-mode`, it seems to work for `M-f` for instance but double-clicking on it will still only select only one of the two halfs (maybe that’s a bug in `superword-mode`?)

Comment: See [`(elisp) Word Motion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Word-Motion.html) around "Characters that belong..." for explanation. [Bug #10494](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10494) has some discussion on changing it. Not sure about `superword-mode`, probably a bug.

Comment: @npostavs: Please consider posting your comment as an answer. The doc you cite seems to point to the culprit and how to change the behavior.